guix installed emacs packages are duplicated - listed twice - in emacs Explore Packages list
I have installed guix on top of Debian, then used guix to install emacs, and a couple emacs packages (emacs-discover and emacs-mastodon), which also caused guix to install some dependencies of those packages.
Every package installed by guix shows up twice in the list in the built-in package manager in emacs. To be clear, they aren't showing up twice because they are available in another repository like elpa or melpa. They didn't show up at all until installed by guix, and they are listed as "external" in the status column of the list (screenshot attached).
Is there a way to fix this? It's going to get real annoying having lots of packages duplicated.


So, it turns out that guix, during installation of either emacs or emacs packages, automatically updated $GUIX_PROFILE/etc/profile with the line:
export EMACSLOADPATH="${GUIX_PROFILE:-/gnu/store/aw9nzpanmzpnf0j3fdh6vlv05d95si6c-profile}/share/emacs/site-lisp${EMACSLOADPATH:+:}$EMACSLOADPATH"
Then guix automatically sources that profile script to update the user environment so that newly installed packages can be found.
However, guix sourced the profile twice (maybe once when installing emacs and once when installing the emacs packages; or perhaps once for each emacs package I installed), leading to the result that my environment variable had the site-lisp dir duplicated in the environment variable. Emacs package tool inside of emacs apparently will happily scan the same dir twice and add entries both times it finds the packages in the same dir.
The resolution is super simple: logout of your shell to clear the environment, then log back in to get a new shell and the env variable will only have the dir once.

Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: Accept Your Own Answers.
